# Print Multi-dimenstional Array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Given the array below what is the simplest way to print it? Looping is one option but is there any other simpler option?

```
val array = arrayOf(arrayOf(1, 2),
arrayOf(3, 4),
arrayOf(5, 6, 7))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Using standard library**

```
val array = arrayOf(arrayOf(1, 2),
            arrayOf(3, 4),
            arrayOf(5, 6, 7))

print(Arrays.deepToString(array))
```

**2. Using for loop**

```
fun <T> print2DArray(twoDArray: Array<Array<T>>) {
    for (i in 0 until twoDArray.size) {
        for (j in 0 until twoDArray[i].size) {
            print(twoDArray[i][j])
            if (j != twoDArray[i].size - 1) print(" ")
        }
        if (i != twoDArray.size - 1) println()
    }
}
```

> ```
> val array = arrayOf(arrayOf(1, 2),
>             arrayOf(3, 4),
>             arrayOf(5, 6, 7))
>
> print2DArray(array)
> ```

Comment: Whoever down-voted can you please comment whats the reason for downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

There is built-in functionality for this:

```
val array = arrayOf(arrayOf(1, 2),
                arrayOf(3, 4),
                arrayOf(5, 6, 7))

println(array.joinToString(prefix = "[", postfix = "]") {
    it.joinToString(prefix = "[", postfix = "]")
})
```

Comment: println(Arrays.deepToString(twoDArray)) is giving me the same output as your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following

```
println(array.contentDeepToString())
```

Answer (score -1):

That depends on the way you want to show it.

#### Option 1

```
fun Array.contentDeepToString: String
```

> Returns a string representation of the contents of this array as if it is a List. Nested arrays are treated as lists too.
>   If any of arrays contains itself on any nesting level that reference is rendered as "[...]" to prevent recursion.

Note this is an inlined function using `Arrays.deepToString(array)` under the hood.

Then using `array.contentDeepToString()` you get in the output this string:

> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7]]

#### Option 2

I mostly use `Array.joinToString`, its allow to join the array using a given separator and applying a transformation to each element. From the doc:

> Creates a string from all the elements separated using [separator] and using the given [prefix] and [postfix] if supplied. If the collection could be huge, you can specify a non-negative value of [limit], in which case only the first [limit]
>   elements will be appended, followed by the [truncated] string (which defaults to "...")

In your case as each item of your array is a subarray, you have to apply a transformation for them also using

```
array.joinToString("\n") { subarray ->
    subarray.joinToString()
}
```

This give you an output as:

> 1, 2
>   3, 4
>   5, 6, 7

You can play with *separator, prefix, postfix, and transformation* parameters to get your wanted format.

---

#### Final notes

- Looping is kind of the only way to format an array, either `contentDeepToString` and `joinToString` use for loop in their implementation, take this in consideration.
- `joinToString` is also available for `Iterable` and `Sequence`